# SQLite and MS SQL Maintain data integrity with Custom Docs and Images

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, data-integrity

I'm creating website with a document WYSIWYG creator/editor that also has the ability to inject images into the document.

If I were designing a DB for just MS SQL I would have `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field to store the html that the user entered and I would also store the uploaded images to the server and simply reference the filepath.

My question is concerning maintaining data integrity between MS SQL and SQLite. I need to ensure that if connection is lost, the SQLite database will maintain current data and when connections are up again, the DBs will communicate and store the latest data.

Under these conditions (an offline SQLite DB) I can't store the images on the server and reference the filepath. Is the only way to store the image as a `BLOB` within the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field?

Comment: No, and using nvarchar(max) is the wrong way to store images. You should use varbinary(MAX). Or even better would be to get the images out of the database entirely.

Comment: @SeanLange NVARCHAR(MAX) would be to store the user input text. My question was concerning how injected images (within the document) are handled. I previously stated that if I only had MS SQL, i would remove all images from DB and store them on server, but now that I have to communicate with an external SQLite DB (that can or cannot access the stored images), how do I handle this

Comment: If you are talking about something like a word document or email with images then I would still store them in varbinary(max)